# c# open file, path starting with %userprofile%

Tags: c#, file

I have a simple problem. I have a path to a file in user directory that looks like this:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\MyProg\settings.file
```

When I try to open it as a file

```
ostream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
```

It spits error because it tries to add `%userprofile%` to the current directory, so it becomes:

```
C:\Program Files\MyProg\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\MyProg\settings.file
```

How do I make it recognise that a path starting with `%USERPROFILE%` is an absolute, not a relative path?

PS: I cannot use

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

Because I need to just open the file by its name. User specifies the name. If user specifies "settings.file", I need to open a file relative to program dir, if user specifies a path starting with `%USERPROFILE%` or some other thing that converts to C:\something, I need to open it as well!

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Use [`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx) on the path before using it.

```
var pathWithEnv = @"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\MyProg\settings.file";
var filePath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(pathWithEnv);

using(ostream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
{
   //...
}
```

Comment: Why not just `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)`?

Comment: Because this is more general - you are assuming that the environment variable passed in will always be `%USERPROFILE%` - what if it is something else? (which is what the question is asking - it is asking about expanding the environment variable - that the example used is the user profile is incidental).

Comment: Ahh, I see. Bad example the OP gave

Comment: It's a terrible example the OP gave if that's what the question really is.  As is, this is very bad practice, and you should be using `Environment.GetFolderPath` for such things.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 I'm doing the same thing, because I want the path of the file to be read, specified in web.config. I want them to be able to put it anywhere, or in the user profile directory of the ID running it. If I used Environment.GetFolderPath, I would have to dictate the file be located in the User Profile. So this way, they can if they want.

Comment: `Environment.GetFolderPath(string)` is not available in .NET Core, so you should use `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(string)` as the answer suggests

Answer (score 7):

Try using [ExpandEnvironmentVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx) on the path.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables` static method:

```
string fileName= Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(fileName);
ostream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
```

Comment: Don't forget to use a `using` statement for the stream.

Answer (score 5):

I use this in my Utilities library.

```
using System;
namespace Utilities
{
    public static class MyProfile
   {
        public static string Path(string target)
        {
            string basePath = 
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + 
@"\Automation\";
            return basePath + target;
        }
    }
}
```

So I can simply use e.g. "string testBenchPath = MyProfile.Path("TestResults");"

Comment: Combine paths by using [Path.Combine()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `Environment.Username` constant as well. Both of the `%USERPROFILE%` and this Environment variable points the same( which is the currently logged user). But if you choose this way, you have to concatenate the path by yourself.

Comment: Ok, there is a little difference, what I forgot. The environment variable means "C:\Users\{username}" while the other only the "{username}"

Comment: No. The username might not be the same as the user profile folder name, please do not assume this. (Consider when folder already exists and a new user of the same name is being created - Windows will pick a new folder name)