# how to open external application in special directories

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently looking for a way to open an external application that's located in the userprofile folder. This is my current codes:

```
    Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo

    'program function'
    p.FileName = "%userprofile%/folder/app.exe"
    Process.Start(p)
```

I got no luck so far. If anyone knows how to do this that would be nice

Comment: Use `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables()` to expand `%userprofile%`; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9993587/273200)

Comment: that's for C# I'm currently looking for a way in vb.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
p.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%userprofile%/folder/app.exe")
```