# Process.Start - Directory - Instead of %userprofile%

Tags: c#, wpf, path

**Hi all,**

I'm new to WPF in c#, and need to know how I can replace my username with something with the basic equivalent to `%userprofile%` so that the file will run on other computers.

I've looked at many questions like this, but can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

**What I have so far..**

```
Process.Start(@"C:\\Users\Alexander\Desktop\She's here\She's here..lnk");
```

*This works on my computer, but I need it to work in all instances.*

I've tried using environment.find and I can't seem to understand it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a path to the desktop for current user in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634142/how-to-get-a-path-to-the-desktop-for-current-user-in-c) & `Path.Combine()`

Comment: The link you just attached has helped, but I need it to be directed to a folder on my desktop and then to the file in that folder. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# open file, path starting with %userprofile%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993561/c-sharp-open-file-path-starting-with-userprofile)

Comment: Actually, I think this question is a better fit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993561/c-sharp-open-file-path-starting-with-userprofile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this:

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop
```

> The logical Desktop rather than the physical file system location.

Which combined with Environment.GetFolderPath returns:

> The path to the specified system special folder

So you should use it like this:

```
string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
Process.Start(Path.Combine(desktop, "She's here", "She's here..lnk"));
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I was really confused of how to do this and this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use use [Environment.SpecialFolderNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var userFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
var filePath = Path.Combine(userFolder, @"She's here\She's here..lnk");
```

> Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory :
>   The directory used to physically store file objects on the desktop.

Comment: Thank you for your help.