# Connect .pst files to Outlook (2016)

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2016, pst

I'm looking for a way to run a one time script when a user opens outlook for the first time that will open an array of outlook data files (.pst)

(The equivalent of using Outlook(2016) and going to File -> Open & Export -> Open Outlook Data Files)

I've searched for registry entries to potentially configure but have not found any that seem to configure which .pst files Outlook has open.

Opening a .pst file directly does not work as Outlook requires that it be opened from within...

I've also done some minor exploring with creating an Outlook Plugin but not sure if that is the right route to go for something that *should* be simple.

Can anyone shed any light on registry keys or other settings to configure what .pst files Outlook opens?

-EDIT: Ok, I swear this did not show up on any of my searches before:
[Is there a way to import PST files into Outlook using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49559535/is-there-a-way-to-import-pst-files-into-outlook-using-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `Application.Session.AddStore` / `AddStoreEx` for each PST file that you need to open.