# How do I create a directory using user profile environment variable?

Tags: c#, directory, path, io, system

I'm having trouble creating a directory that is supposed to be located in a user's documents file.

Code

:    `string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine("%UserProfile%\\Documents", "MyDir");`
`System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);`

Once this is run it doesn't create anything at all. I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong here, I've also tried inputting the string manually with no luck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993561/c-sharp-open-file-path-starting-with-userprofile

Comment: The following code works, I made two changes but I think my problem was that I was forgetting to put the ending \ on my directory

System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\MyDir\");