# Specify user documents directory in app.config file in C#

Tags: c#, config

I would like to access my users documents directory in order to store a log file.  The user does not have admin rights, so I cannot store it in a protected directory, such as program files.  Currently, the app.config setting is:

```
<add key="BasicLog" value="%Data%\SerialNumberTracker.log"/>
```

Which is not working because the user doesn't have admin right.  Is there a %X% setting where X = the users documents folder?  Also, direction to a place where I could see a list of these keys, such as %Data% would be awesome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# open file, path starting with %userprofile%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993561/c-sharp-open-file-path-starting-with-userprofile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to change it to

```xml
<add key="BasicLog" value="%USERPROFILE%\Documents\SerialNumberTracker.log"/>
```

Then in your code once you have the value in a variable e.g. `basicLog`, you would use

```cs
string path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(basicLog);
```

You can see similar ones to these by opening a command prompt and typing `set`.

There's also a list [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-recognized-environment-variables) where you can find more info on the ones from the command prompt window and whether they are available in user or system context.

Comment: I see what you're saying, and unfortunately, it's not working for me.  Not sure why that is.  If I use %Data%, then when I look where it wants to write, it shows the path C:/ProgramData/SerialNumberTracker.log, but if I use %USERPROFILE% or any rendition thereof, it shows the path as %USERPROFILE%/Documents/SerialNumberTracker.log.

Comment: Ah!  Nevermind, it's putting it into the Public User documents.  Awesome, thank you!