# File.Copy procedure attempts to copy to the app's exe path as well as what I specify; how do I rectify this?

Tags: vb.net

This is what I currently have:

```
Dim sm As String = "%userprofile%\start menu\programs\CatsWithCaptions"
File.Copy(Form1.txtFPath.Text & "\Publish\Cats With Captions.lnk", sm)
```

The error:

> F:\VB.NET\Setups\Test%userprofile%\start menu\programs\CatsWithCaptions.lnk path doesn't exist.

For clarity, the "`F:\VB.NET\Setups\Test`" section should not be present.

Sorry for lack of actual error handling - I cannot test within VS.

Using VS Enterprise 2023.

Comment: See this answer [open file, path starting with %userprofile%](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9993587/9365244)

Comment: @JayV Unfortunately this doesn't work - the same thing happens. Could it be something to do with me running it as admin?  Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Thanks. I found it, using CurrentDirectory

Comment: @user246821 I have found it, just need to figure out how to close question. Thanks anyway.